# Why can't I input two string consecutively in java?

Tags: java

My program terminates after taking one string input. It doesn't take string 2 input.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scn= new Scanner(System.in);
        int T ;
        T=scn.nextInt();
        while(T!=0){
            String s1 = scn.nextLine(); // after i give input for the first string ,program terminates!
            String s2 = scn.nextLine(); // program terminates before asking for s2 input
            System.out.println(isMetaString(s1,s2));
            T--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scn= new Scanner(System.in);
    int T ;
    T=scn.nextInt();

    // scn.nextLine();  // for enter.
    // here after entering int value, 
    // you must be pressing enter,
    // that 'enter' is getting stored in s1,
    // and then when you give first string it is getting stored in s2 
    // and that is why your program is terminating.

    while(T!=0){
        String s1 = scn.nextLine(); // after i give input for the first string ,program terminates!
        String s2 = scn.nextLine(); // program terminates before asking for s2 input
        System.out.println(isMetaString(s1,s2));
        T--;
    }
}
```

**Solution : add sca.nextLine() after sca.nextInt() It. will resolve the issue**

Answer (score 0):

`T = scn.nextInt();` - with this line you assign an `int` value to variable `T`, but there is a new line character left that you didn't take care of (this it the character that you created when pressing `Enter` after your input. You might want to add `sc.nextLine()` right after this line or change:

`T = scn.nextInt();`

to:

`T = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());` This method will take care of a new line character following int assigned to `T`.

*By the way, remember that this is good to follow Java naming conventions to keep you code easy to read for others. When naming variables use camelCase.*

Comment: @RaviKiranKrovvidi Glad that I could help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here after giving the number as input you might be hitting enter to go to the next line, but to the system the enter i.e a blank space is an input itself, which is stored in your first string input i.e s1, and the string that you give as input is getting stored in the second string i.e s2.

So your program is not getting terminated after taking the input for s1, it is taking the integer input for T, then it takes the enter (i.e blank space) as an input for s1 and then s2 takes the final string input and after that the program is terminated.

To resolve this what you can do is Do Not hit enter after entering the integer input i.e value of T, give a space and then just give the string input for s1, then hit enter and give input for s2, but remember you will get an extra space in the starting of s1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).